# Live Sass Compiler not compiling

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, live-sass-compiler

I have used the live sass compiler a few hours back, it worked fine, but now it's not working. Can you please let me know what can be the problem?

This is what I see when I hit ctrl + s
[image]

This is my project folder structure
[image]

This is settings in settings.json   [image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any other folders open at the same time in Visual Studio? This happened to me one day and by closing all the folders started working again. It doesn't work by just restarting Visual Studio, you have to close them by hand.

The settings.json seems alright and the compiler isn't showing any errors.

Comment: Later i have seen that the compiler is working if i save the main scss file. but not working if i save the partial scss files those are included in the main scss files. so if i work on a partial file then i have to hit save on main scss file as well.